# Reverse DNS script with Regex in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, reverse-dns

I am currently working on a reverse DNS script intended to open a log file, find the IP address, then resolve the IP to DNS. I have a regex set up to identify the IP address in the file, but when I added `socket.gethostbyaddr` to my script the script ignores my regex and still lists objects in the file that are not IP addresses. I've never used Python before, but this is what I have right now:

```
import socket
import re

f = open('ipidk.txt' , 'r')

lines = f.readlines()

raw_data = str(f.readlines())

regex = r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})'

foundip = re.findall( regex, raw_data )

for raw_data in lines:
    host = raw_data.strip()

    try:
        dns = socket.gethostbyaddr(host)
        print("%s - %s" % (host, dns))
    except socket.error as exc:
        pass

        f.close()
```

Comment: `regex` is only used in `foundip = re.findall( regex, raw_data )`, but `foundip` is never used in the loop, so whatever values caught by the regex are ignored. You probably meant to iterate over `foundip`, not `lines`.

Comment: when I use ```found ip``` nothing comes back as if it didn't even read the text file, so I tried commenting out ```raw_data``` and ```regex``` and putting ```lines``` in order to see the IP addresses in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `f.readlines()` twice. The first time reads everything in the file, and puts that in `lines`. The second time has nothing left to read (it starts reading from the current file position, it doesn't rewind to the beginning), so it returns an empty list, and `raw_data` will just be `"[]"`, with no IPs.

Just call `f.read()` once, and assign that to `raw_data`.

Then you need to loop over the IPs found with the regexp, not `lines`.

```
import socket
import re

with open('ipidk.txt' , 'r') as f:
    raw_data = f.read()
regex = r'(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}'

foundip = re.findall( regex, raw_data )
for host in foundip:
    try:
        dns = socket.gethostbyaddr(host)
        print("%s - %s" % (host, dns))
    except socket.error as exc:
        pass
```